# Teclado virtual, sobrepondo ou comprimindo elementos

Tags: android, teclado

Preciso de ajuda na seguinte situação.

Tenho algumas Activity feitas, com vários momentos de interação com *EditText* e *Button*. Em certas telas, o Layout comprime quando abre o teclado virtual do Android, e em outras ele omite algumas informações sobrepondo as mesmas.

Gostaria de saber na realidade como que posso controlar o uso destas situações de omitir e comprimir os elementos da Activity ao abrir o teclado virtual do Android com toque em um *EditText*.

Se alguém puder me auxiliar ficaria muito agradecido!

Comment: Isto, esta resposta que tu indicou resolveu o problema.

Comment: Apenas para documentarmos aqui, se usa o: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan".

Em minha Activity mantive o teclado virtual inicialmente escondido, e ao ficar visível, o teclado não deformou(comprimiu) os elementos. Então no AndroidManifest defini o seguinte:

        <activity
            android:name=".modulo_auditoria.AuditoriaActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />.